# Use sed to transform a comma space seperated list into a comma seperated list with quotes around each element

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I have this

```
a/b/Test b/c/Test c/d/Test
```

and want to transform it into:

```
"a/b/Test", "b/c/Test", "c/d/Test"
```

I know I can use this (here: `path=a/b/Test b/c/Test c/d/Test`)

```
test=$(echo $path | sed 's/ /", "/g')
```

to transform it into

```
a/b/Test", "b/c/Test", "c/d/Test
```

But here I am missing the first and last `"`.

I dont quite know how to use `sed` for this. Can I somehow change it and use the anchors `^` and `$` to get the first and last part of the string and add `"` there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sed  's/.*/"&"/g ; s/ /", "/g' filename
```

Comment: Nice! Would you mind explaining: `s/.*/"&"/g`? Thanks!

Comment: .* is is used to print the " in the beginning and ending of the string. You can change the character as you want. suppose    s/.*/a&r/g. It print a in the beginning and r in the last of string. and the next step s/ /", "/ think you know very well.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `awk`:

```
s='a/b/Test b/c/Test c/d/Test'
awk -v OFS=', ' '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) $i = "\"" $i "\""} 1' <<< "$s"
```

```
"a/b/Test", "b/c/Test", "c/d/Test"
```

Answer (score 0):

awk is easier:

```
awk -v OFS=", " -v q='"' '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)$i=q $i q}7'
```

Answer (score 0):

You may just add double quotes **if you have a single line text**:

```
test="a/b/Test b/c/Test c/d/Test"
test='"'$(echo "$test" | sed 's/[[:space:]]\{1,\}/",&"/g')'"'
echo "$test"
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/KajqWc)

If you have multiple lines use

```
test=$(echo "$test" | sed 's/[[:space:]]\{1,\}/",&"/g; s/^/"/g; s/$/"/g')
test=$(echo "$test" | sed -E 's/[[:space:]]+/",&"/g; s/^|$/"/g')
```

See [this online demo](https://ideone.com/1yRnHW)

The `[[:space:]]\{1,\}` POSIX BRE pattern (equal to `[[:space:]]+` POSIX ERE) matches one or more whitespace chars and `&` in the replacement pattern inserts this matched value back in the resulting string.